# does EntityFrameworkDataService close the db connection after querying?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I have an EntityFrameworkDataService implemented on a server application where client applications can query from it. I googled around for a while but couldn't find out how to close the database connection once we're done with a query. Is there a way to do this or is it done automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The Entity Framework opens connections only when required, for example to execute a query or to call SaveChanges, and then closes the connection when the operation is complete.

I've no reason at all to assume that `EntityFrameworkDataService<T>` will force its `DbContext` to keep connections open. Of course you can always check by profiling the database.